# T440s randomly freezing on Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, freeze, intel

My T440s thinkpad randomly freezes when running both the LTS and current Ubuntu release. I haven't be able to identify a pattern to the freezes.

This happened on Mint 17.1, so I tried fresh installs of Ubuntu 15.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 and it happens on both.

I have Intel Graphics.

No escape shortcuts seem to work, I've tried all of them including `ctrl-alt-backspace` and `alt-printscrn-R/E/I/S/U/B`

Here are my last 10 minutes of syslog entries before it freezes up, if anyone can offer suggestions I'd be very happy!

```
Jun 18 13:55:01 rathboma-thinkpad signond[19525]: QObject::disconnect: Unexpected null parameter
Jun 18 13:55:06 rathboma-thinkpad ntpdate[19768]: adjust time server 91.189.89.199 offset -0.007403 sec
Jun 18 13:55:19 rathboma-thinkpad AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting due to inactivity
Jun 18 13:55:19 rathboma-thinkpad AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting was requested
Jun 18 13:55:19 rathboma-thinkpad org.debian.apt[750]: 13:55:19 AptDaemon [INFO]: Quitting due to inactivity
Jun 18 13:55:19 rathboma-thinkpad org.debian.apt[750]: 13:55:19 AptDaemon [INFO]: Quitting was requested
Jun 18 13:55:27 rathboma-thinkpad ntpdate[19818]: adjust time server 91.189.89.199 offset 0.002787 sec
Jun 18 13:55:43 rathboma-thinkpad gnome-session[1788]: [7316:7316:0618/185543:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(11539)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D07020FCAA180000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glTexStorage2DEXT: <- error from previous GL command
Jun 18 13:55:49 rathboma-thinkpad gnome-session[1788]: [WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED
Jun 18 13:55:54 rathboma-thinkpad gnome-session[1788]: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Jun 18 13:55:54 rathboma-thinkpad com.ubuntu.OneConf[1683]: WARNING:oneconf.hosts:Error in loading other_hosts file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/rathboma/.cache/oneconf/9e2f458505b84348ac5265c279472395/other_hosts'
Jun 18 13:56:45 rathboma-thinkpad gnome-session[1788]: [7316:7316:0618/185645:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(11539)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D0F0B618AB180000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glTexStorage2DEXT: <- error from previous GL command
Jun 18 13:56:47 rathboma-thinkpad gnome-session[1788]: [7275:7312:0618/135647:ERROR:channel.cc(300)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)
Jun 18 13:56:49 rathboma-thinkpad gnome-session[1788]: [7316:7316:0618/185649:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(11539)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D0709D0DAB180000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glTexStorage2DEXT: <- error from previous GL command
Jun 18 14:00:41 rathboma-thinkpad gnome-session[1788]: [7316:7316:0618/190041:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(11539)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D0F0B618AB180000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glTexStorage2DEXT: <- error from previous GL command
Jun 18 14:01:03 rathboma-thinkpad gnome-session[1788]: [7275:7312:0618/140103:ERROR:channel.cc(300)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)
Jun 18 14:03:42 rathboma-thinkpad gnome-session[1788]: [7275:7312:0618/140342:ERROR:channel.cc(300)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)
Jun 18 14:03:48 rathboma-thinkpad gnome-session[1788]: [7275:7275:0618/140348:ERROR:extension_host.cc(367)] Killing renderer for extension eifdbcbnlahelniokpkpdlhaocgjdcje for sending an EventAck message with a bad event id.
Jun 18 14:03:48 rathboma-thinkpad gnome-session[1788]: [7275:7275:0618/140348:ERROR:bad_message.cc(16)] Terminating extension renderer for bad IPC message, reason 3
Jun 18 14:05:50 rathboma-thinkpad gnome-session[1788]: ERROR 2015-06-18 14:05:50 unityfree <unknown>:0 g_sequence_get: assertion '!is_end (iter)' failed
Jun 18 14:05:50 rathboma-thinkpad gnome-session[1788]: ERROR 2015-06-18 14:05:50 unity null <unknown>:0 Unable to get value. NULL row data in DeeSequenceModel@0x2d300b0 at position 1. The row has probably been removed
Jun 18 14:05:50 rathboma-thinkpad gnome-session[1788]: ERROR 2015-06-18 14:05:50 unity null <unknown>:0 Unable to get string. Column 5 in DeeSequenceModel@0x2d300b0 holds a NULL value in row 1
```

Comment: encountered similar issue after installing newer version of intel graphics driver

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 15.04 now, I haven't manually updated any drivers but it still happens -- usually when I'm out of the house connecting to other wi-fi points (unsure if this is related). No idea how to solve it. The next time it happens when I'm on site with a customer I'm just going to jump ship to apple I think.

Comment: I guess in your case Unity is freezing when perform some GPU calculation. I don't use unity, but if there is option to disable GPU accelerated visual effects or something like that. But root of the problem is in Intel graphics driver. Another option is to try to install newer version of driver from  https://01.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)